# Realtek WiFi DRIVER installation (w/o ethernet connection)

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

*Hello,*

how to install the driver for **Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac** - **without the availability of ANY other internet connection**?

There are several guides on how to do it using a wired connection, but nothing about without it.

NOTE: The PC of interest has **Losedows pre-installed**, thus it is possible to **pre-download the driver (file) and store it in a destination visible to Ubuntu**.

Btw., I prefer the oldest (possible) Ubuntu still supported **(16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS)**.

*THANKS in advance.*

**PS: Why can't [comrade Cosmonaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Shuttleworth) just supply all available drivers within the default Kernel - installation ISO?**

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't comrade Cosmonaut just supply all available drivers within
> the default Kernel - installation ISO?

Because many devices and their Linux drivers were developed and shipped *after* the date of the Ubuntu versions you reference. RTL8821CE and its suitable Linux driver were not available in April, 2018 or earlier. Moreover, although there is some overlap in terms of contributions to kernel development, Ubuntu, Canonical and Mr. Shuttleworth are not the gatekeepers of the Linux kernel.

Building the driver without a working internet connection is difficult but not impossible. If this is a laptop and you have the option to walk it to a friend's house that has ethernet or else tether your phone, it can be done in three minutes or so. If not, here is how to do it in three hours or so.

If, as I hope, you are planning to install Ubuntu from a DVD or USB, then they both contain the most essential part of the process, a package named, not coincidentally, *build-essential*. This method, although it is tedious, will work. The list of deb files you need is this (with the exception of bcmwl-kernel-source): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GbZ689gYXw/

Browse the USB or DVD drive and look in pool/main/b for build-essential; in pool/main/d for dkms and dpkg-dev; in pool/main/f for fakeroot and so on. Continue until every package on the list I provided is dragged on to the desktop of the new Ubuntu installation. Now let’s install the driver. Please download this file and transfer it to the desktop of the Ubuntu machine: https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/archive/master.zip Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.'

Now, open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
cd rtl8821ce-master
sudo dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821ce
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: THANKS for your help!

Comment: CANONICAL tweaks much of the code (Debian base, Gnome...), but not the Kernel? 16.04.6 released in Feb 2019, 18.04.4 in Feb 2020, 20.04 in Apr 2020 - there was plenty of time to implement. They modify the unnecessary, but ignore the ESSENTIAL!

Comment: The source you linked (https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) points as well to a PRE-BUILT BINARY .DEB package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/rtl8821ce-dkms - https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/all/rtl8821ce-dkms/download), maintained by Ubuntu MOTU Developers (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU) - another reason to be implemented "in factory", btw. ... However, can that .DEB be used, pre-saved in Losedows, instead of the complicated process you describe?

Comment: Certainly; however, note that the package requires two dependencies,  *dkms* and *bc* which themselves also have dependencies such as libc6, which I listed, as well as others.. I am unable to tell you which process will ultimately be shorter.

Comment: THANKS, @chili555! ... The dependencies are not included in the basic Ubuntu installation?

Comment: No, but, as I said in my answer above, they are probably on the installation USB or DVD for those relatively few cases where one needs to compile a driver.

Comment: THANKS, I'll try.